# MySQL multiple rows

Tags: mysql, database, rows

I am learning databases and I'm hitting an issue and I want someone to explain it to me.
I have a table.

```
car     | car_id | car_type
________________________________
bmw     |   1    | <bmwcartype1>
bmw     |   1    | <bmwcartype2>
bmw     |   1    | <bmwcartype3>
bmw     |   1    | <bmwcartype4>
mercedes|   2    | <mercedescartype1>
mercedes|   2    | <mercedescartype2>
mercedes|   2    | <mercedescartype3>
lexus   |   3    | <lexuscartype1>
lexus   |   3    | <lexuscartype2>
lexus   |   3    | <lexuscartype3>
lexus   |   3    | <lexuscartype4>
lexus   |   3    | <lexuscartype5>
```

I want to display for example the car and the number of cartypes. I'm not sure how to explain this but on the table above I only managed to get the first row.

SELECT car, COUNT(car) AS number_of_cars FROM cars WHERE car_id = 1

This is displaying the first row like:

```
car | number_of_cars
bmw |   4
```

And I want the following rows to be:

```
car      | number_of_cars
bmw      | 4
mercedes | 3
lexus    | 5
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Instead of the `where` clause, add `group by car`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff That was exactly what I was looking for, Gordon. Can you post your answer properly so I can mark it as solved and rate you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an aggregation query that returns one row.  Just as a note, this query works in MySQL but would fail in most databases.  The column `car` is not in a `group by`.  Even though you are choosing only one value, SQL engines don't usually allow this (MySQL is an exception).

The query that you want is:

```
SELECT car, COUNT(car) AS number_of_cars
FROM cars
group by car;
```

Note that `car` appear both in the `select` and `group by`.  Although you could have `car_id` in the `group by`. this is bad form.  Try to be sure that the unaggregated columns in the `select` are always in the `group by` -- at least until you really understand what you are doing with SQL.